# Apply Grayscale with OpenCv

Tags: c, opencv, lua, threshold

I´m trying to work with C, Lua and OpenCv but I´m having problems with OpenCv methods.

First, I want to apply grayscale into an image. I´m trying this:

```
static int treatments_grayscale (lua_State * L) {
    void *ptr;
    ptr=lua_touserdata(L,1);

    int w,h;
    w=lua_tointeger(L,2);
    h=lua_tointeger(L,3);

    cv::Mat * img=new cv::Mat(w,h,CV_8UC4,ptr);

    cvCvtColor(img,img,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    // Return image
    lua_pushlstring(L,(char *)img->data,w*h*4);
    return 1;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

"Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat"

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried like this:

```
cv::Mat * img=new cv::Mat(w,h,CV_8UC4,ptr);

IplImage * dst_img= cvCreateImage(cvSize(w,h), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
dst_img->imageData = (char *) img->data;      

cvCvtColor(dst_img,dst_img,CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

And then... the error:

"error: (-215) dst.data == dst0.data in function cvCvtColor"

Thank you! =)

Comment: Perhaps not related to your problem, but why send the entire image into Lua as a string? Wouldn't a pointer (=userdata) suffice?

Comment: Actually I have to change this =) ...and I will... I´m just trying to understand this filter errors before... but thanks for the advice @lhf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is an error because the source image should not have the same size as the destination image.
When i convert a rgb image to gray i use something like that :

```
IplImage * cvImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
IplImage * cvGray = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvImage->imageData = (char *) img->data;
cvCvtColor(cvImage, cvGray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

Comment: I´m not getting an error anymore =) ...but the problem now is.. how will I return this image? "lua_pushlstring(L,cvGray->imageData,w*h*4);" gives me a segmentation fault =/

Comment: try : cvCvtColor(cvGray, cvImage, CV_GRAY2RGB); then lua_pushlstring(L,cvImage->imageData,w*h*4); to have the same size of data. That's a bit overkill. Will you do other thing with opencv ?

Comment: I will =) ...This caused an error: "Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor"... actually I´m trying to use all the filters that I need and then improve my code... thanks @lino =)

Comment: The problem is always on the number of channel for each images, opencv rgb image use 3 Channel, Gray image use 1 channel. And it seems you want a 4 Channel Image.

Comment: Actually I put 4 just because I didn´t know how channels work.. using "lua_pushlstring(L,cvGray->imageData,w*h);" the problem persists =/

Comment: try   cv::Mat * img=new cv::Mat(w,h,CV_8UC3,ptr); and lua_pushlstring(L,cvGray->imageData,w*h*3); I really don't know how many channels lua has maybe if you print ptr->type(); it will help you